# How to show $\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{H_{n-1}}{\log n}<\infty$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, inequality

This makes sense to me intuitively, because $\log n\approx1+\cdots+\frac{1}{n}$, so the quotient $\frac{H_{n-1}}{\log n}$ "should" eventually be $\leq1$. However it seems the function $f(n)=H_{n-1}-\log n$ is increasing
$$\log(n+1)-\log(n)=\int_n^{n+1}\frac{1}{x}\leq\frac{1}{n}=H_n-H_{n-1}$$
and $f(2)\geq0$, which would suggest $H_{n-1}\geq\log n$ for all $n$, contradicting what I am trying to prove.

Comment: Still, $\int _{n} ^{n + 1} \frac{1}{x} \ge \frac{1}{2 n}$ for sufficiently large $n$, so one can show the supremum is at most $2$. Between $1$ and $\infty$, there's some leeway to stand on.

Comment: @Gassa OK, I think I worked it out: $\int _{n} ^{n + 1} \frac{1}{x} \geq\frac{1}{n+1}\geq\frac{1}{2 n}\Rightarrow H_{n-1}-2\log n$ is decreasing $\Rightarrow H_{n-1}\leq2\log n$ for all $n$. Does this look correct?

Comment: Looks fine to me...

Comment: $H_{n-1}/\log n\ge1$ does not "contradict" $\limsup_{n\to\infty}H_{n-1}/\log n<\infty$. I suspect the issue is you're thinking $H_{n-1}-\log n$ being increasing implies it tends to $\infty$ (which *would* contradict what you're trying to prove). This assumption is false: $H_{n-1}-\log n$ tends towards the Euler-Mascheroni constant $\gamma\approx0.577$ from below, so it is increasing but bounded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\log(n+1)-\log(n)
=\int_n^{n+1}\frac{1}{x}
\le\frac{1}{n}
=H_{n}-H_{n-1}
$
so

$\begin{array}\\
H_{n-1}-1
&=\sum_{k=2}^{n-1}(H_{k}-H_{k-1})\\
&\ge\sum_{k=2}^{n-1}(\log(k+1)-\log(k)\\
&=\log(n)-\log(2)\\
\end{array}
$

so
$H(n)
=H(n-1)+\dfrac1{n}
\ge \log(n)+1-\log(2)+\dfrac1{n}
$
so
$\dfrac{H((n)}{\log(n)}
\ge 1+\dfrac{1-\log(2)}{\log(n)}+\dfrac1{n\log(n)}
$.

You also have
$\log(n+1)-\log(n)
=\int_n^{n+1}\frac{1}{x}
\ge\frac{1}{n+1}
=H_{n+1}-H_{n}
$
so

$\begin{array}\\
H_n-1
&=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}(H_{k+1}-H_k)\\
&\le\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}(\log(k+1)-\log(k)\\
&=\log(n)\\
\end{array}
$

so
$H(n)
\le \log(n)+1
$
or
$\dfrac{H_n}{\log(n)}
\le 1+\dfrac1{\log(n)}
$.